# Is there a way to limit per_process memory on a shared vgpu with Spacy, Torch, etc?

Tags: kubernetes, pytorch, spacy, kubeflow

I'm looking to to find the gpu memory fraction limiting parameters for:

spacy, torch, and other common models.

I know for tensorflow models we can set `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` but is there in an equivalent in pytorch or spacy?

Bonus points if there's a way to allocate memory on shared vgpu to multiple different kinds of models simultaneously?

i.e Spacy models consume .20, Tensorflow models consume .40, and pytorch models consume .30 so we can avoid out of memory errors while serving all of our models on the same cluster with shared vgpu resources.

For a little more context, we're using this virtualgpu plugin
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-virtual-gpu-device-plugin with kubeflow.

Comment: Not at all familiar with gpu, tourch or Spacy... but I know k8s allows you to set memory limits to individual containers in a Pod. If you can split each process into individual containers, they can all be part of the same Pod with different values for `resources`. They will still see each other as localhost and will be able to share local volumes to talk to each other.